# UIView.animatewithDuration not animating when activated by button

Tags: ios, uiview, animatewithduration

So I have a bunch of arrows that I transform once in the viewDidLoad() function like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0) {

        self.Arrow1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-20, 0)
        self.Arrow1.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.Arrow1.transform, -66.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)/180.0)


        self.Arrow2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-9, -8)
        self.Arrow2.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.Arrow2.transform, -70.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)/180.0)

        // And So On...

    }

}
```

but then I try to later move them at the press of a button:

```
   @IBAction func searchPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(5.0) {
            self.Arrow1.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.Arrow1.transform, -100, 0)

            self.Arrow2.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.Arrow2.transform, 0, 100)

           //And So on... (They're 9 Arrows)

        }
    }
```

But then it doesn't animate, or I think it does, but really weirdly. It moves a lot instantly, then starts animating from there. I don't understand why or how I can fix it. [Here is what happens](https://vimeo.com/168420224)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future travelers stuck at the same predicament: You have to control your views using autolayout if they're subview of views using autolayout as well. Otherwise you get the weird results I was getting.

[Here](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/animating-views-auto-layout-ios8-swift) is an excellent guide on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Also put, self.view.layoutIfNeeded inside the block.

Comment: Nothing happens. It still does the same thing